# D-Bus: Export object without ObjectManager

Tags: dbus

I want to create an object and export it at the D-Bus. More exactly I'm using the gdbus and generate the object's code using gdbus-codegen.

The example at the glib page (animal and cat objects) only shows how an object is exported with an objectmanager. The D-Bus specification suggests the usage of the ObjectManager only if there are really multiple objects to manage. Because I only have one object I don't want to use the overhead of the ObjectManager.

In my application (which hosts the objects) I already:

1. Open a connect 'g_bus_own_name'
2. Get the bus acquired callback: 'on_bus_acquired'

What should I do now, to create and export my object?
When I call '...`_skeleton_new()`' I think I'm creating a new '**service-side**' object, is this correct?
Is '`g_dbus_connection_register_object`' the correct way? If yes is there any good example where to all the parameters I have to pass?

I hope someone can help me :)

Best regards
Jean-Pierre

Comment: I think I've found what I was searching for. The function I haven't seen was 'g_dbus_interface_skeleton_export'! Now I'm happy again :)

Comment: you may answer your own question, and even approve it.

Answer (score 2):

I think its too late for response but may be useful for someone else who don't want to
use the `GDBusObjectManager`.

No need to register the interface object created using `..._skeleton_new();`, just export it using `g_dbus_interface_skeleton_export();`

I was having the same requirement as you and got confused with to register or not.

Finally with some code analysis found that `g_dbus_interface_skeleton_export()` 
internally registers the interface object.

Thanks
AruN

Comment: I was a bit confused by your answer, so to clarify to everyone else.  Create your object with `..._skeleton_new();` and then export it via `g_dbus_interface_skeleton_export()`